# Autowiring spring bean by name using annotation

Tags: spring, autowired

In Springs latest version, we can autowire a bean using annotation as `@Autowired`. This will autowire the bean using its type(or constructor, if applied on it).
Is there any way I can use the `@Autowired` annotation based on the bean name which we were doing without annotation in Spring's XML file as **autowire="byName"**?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use JSR-250 `@Resource` for by-name bean autowiring, unless you need constructor injection or multi-parameter method injection.

From the docs:

> If you intend to express annotation-driven injection by name, do not primarily use @Autowired, even if is technically capable of referring to a bean name through @Qualifier values. Instead, use the JSR-250 @Resource annotation, which is semantically defined to identify a specific target component by its unique name, with the declared type being irrelevant for the matching process.

Answer (score 106):

You can use:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("beanname")
```

According to the [@Qualifier javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html)

> This annotation may be used on a field or parameter as a qualifier for candidate beans when autowiring

Comment: Shouldn't be `@Autowired` instead of `@Autowire` ?

Comment: Could you add an example for how to reference the bean qualifier on a parameter?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to define name of the bean with which they will be registered in DI container, you can pass the name in annotation itself e.g. **@Service (“employeeManager”).**

Then using below code you can enable autowire by Name

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("employeeManager")
private EmployeeManagerService employeeManagerService;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use @Component("beanname") in the java class definition of your bean

Then while autowiring use JSR 330

@Inject
@Named(Value="beanname")

Answer (score 2):

I was using bean name proxy which was messing up autowiring by name. @Resource didn't have that issue since it doesn't care about type. So now I know one reason for this recommendation by Spring developers :-) Just FYI

Comment: Yet another reason is mentioned in the Spring docs: ... beans that are themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected through @Autowired, because type matching is not properly applicable to them.