# Spring - How to choose properties in dependent bean?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

Suppose, I have the following beans in my Spring xml:

```
<bean id="mqConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="${host}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${mq.port}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="mqConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

I need to send messages to different hosts, but I don't want define several connection factory beans.

It would be great to specify host something like this:

```
class A {
    @Autowired(host="host1")
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
}

class B {
    @Autowired(host="host2")
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
}
```

### Update:

I can create the following config:

```
<bean id="mqConnectionFactory1" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="${host1}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${mq.port}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mqConnectionFactory2" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="${host2}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${mq.port}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsQueueConnectionFactory1"
      class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="mqConnectionFactory1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsQueueConnectionFactory2"
      class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="mqConnectionFactory2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate1" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate2" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory2"/>
</bean>
```

Then:

```
class A {
    @Resource("jmsTemplate1")
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
}

class B {
    @Resource("jmsTemplate2")
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
}
```

It seems wrong and complicated. The question would be to reduce this config and pass host as parameter. In other words I want to tell Spring: "Create me jmsTemplate and set property host of connectionFactory to this value."

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your proposal is that the JMS connector is a singleton which implies that it is shared among all objects/threads in your application. So changing its host configuration in one object/thread will cause issues to other objects/threads using it.

My suggestion is that you use spring bean "parent" (see *1) to define different jms connections to each of the applicable hosts and then using wiring using @Resource instead of autowire (or @Autowire @Qualifier combination to force a bean see *2)

Edit: Another possible solution is to use FactoryBean(s) though I am not 100% sure of the syntax.

*1 http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-configuration-inheritance/

*2 [Autowiring spring bean by name using annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831261/autowiring-spring-bean-by-name-using-annotation)

Comment: I'm aware of @Resource annotation and bean inheritance, but it isn't suitable for me. It seems that I need a factory that takes host parameter and constructs jmsTemplate with corresponding connection factory. I'll give FactoryBean a try. Thank you!

Comment: As I said in my answer. JMS connectors need to be singletons otherwise you are risking a huge performance hit to have each connection initialized every time you need it. You might want to add caching to your factory.

Comment: If I don't miss something I can just tell Spring to make connection factory a singleton to share (in my case) one physical connection.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

I have different properties files containing connection information for different environments, like local, development and production.

- `db.local.properties`
- `db.dev.properties`
- `db.prod.properties`

I used only one of this properties files when running my application by setting an environment variable:

```
<bean id="dbPlaceholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="location" value="classpath:db.${db.environment:dev}.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Here you can see I used a environment variable called `{db.environment}` if the value is not defined it defaults to dev forming the file name `db.dev.properties`.

My next step is define the variable in the different environments where I run my application

```
java -Ddb.environenment=prod ...
```

Since I am using Tomcat I defined that variable in the `sentenv.sh`, but I am pretty sure other applications servers offer a similar mechanism.

Then I my code I consume the parameters offered by the property file

```
@Value("${db.url}")
private String databaseUrl;
@Value("${db.userName}")
private String userName;
@Value("${db.password}")
private String password;
```

Comment: It seems very useful, I'll remember this trick. But in my case the class must decide to which host it sends messages. In some cases it will use both destinations.

Comment: I see, I thought you question was about an environmental thing, and not that you were actually using both servers. If that's the case I don't see why you want a single connection, if you say you may need then both.

Comment: Of course, I need multiple connections. I don't want to duplicate this config like mqConnectionFactoryHost1, mqConnectionFactoryHost2, jmsTemplateHost1, jmsTemplateHost2. I need to specify host during creation of jmsTemplate.