# How does Spring decouple a class from an interface?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, decoupling

In the official website of Spring framework, there's an example which shows how Spring decouple a class from an interface, or better to say, an implementation if an interface.

Here's the code:

Interface:

```
package hello;

public interface MessageService {
    String getMessage();
}
```

Component Class:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MessagePrinter {

    final private MessageService service;

    @Autowired
    public MessagePrinter(MessageService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println(this.service.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Application:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    @Bean
    MessageService mockMessageService() {
        return new MessageService() {
            public String getMessage() {
              return "Hello World!";
            }
        };
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = 
          new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
      MessagePrinter printer = context.getBean(MessagePrinter.class);
      printer.printMessage();
  }
}
```

What I currently understand about dependency injection is that when a class named `A` need another class named `B` for processing what ever it must do, `B` is a dependency and `A` is dependent. If `B` is an interface, then `A` is dependent on **some** implementation of `B`.

So, in the above code, how `MessagePrinter` is decoupled from `MessageService` implementation ?

we still have to implement `MessageService`, If we don't implement it, can `MessagePrinter` function properly?

Regards

Comment: I think you are looking for `@Qualifier`, see [Autowiring spring bean by name using annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11831261/2970947)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't know what is `@Qualifier`. I just started studying spring and the example is in the first page of website. I can't understand how `MessagePrinter` is decoupled from implementation of `MessageService`

Comment: Click the link I provided. In your example code, **how** is `MessagePrinter` *tied* to a **specific** `MessageService`? Note the `@Autowired` annotation. That is how.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm so confused! what do you mean _tied_? you mean how `MessagePrinter` is dependent to `MessageService`?!! let me ask a question, the term _decoupling_, does it mean `MessagePrinter` doesn't need an implementation of `MessageService` anymore ? If not, then I haven't understood it yet!

Comment: It **does not** mean that. It mean it is not coupled (tied, linked, hardcoded to use) to a ***specific*** implementation; you could replace one `MessageService` with any other implementation of `MessageService`. Or a mock `MessageService` as in your example.

Comment: No, it won't function anyway.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I understand. If we have several implementation of `MessagePrinter`, then we can give `MessageService` whichever we want. But we can do this without Spring either, can't we?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you must have a `MessageService` in your context. Without it, dependency injection caused by `@Autowired` annotation will fail during context initialization.

If I understand the terminology correctly, `MessagePrinter` cannot be decoupled from `MessageService` because the former uses the latter in its code directly. But it can be decoupled from `MessageService` implementations.

It is decoupled from `MessageService` implementations, because it only depends on `MessageService` interface; it does not know anything about implementing classes.

If you happen to have `MessageServiceImpl1` and then change it to `MessageServiceImpl2`, `MessagePrinter` will not have to be changed at all (if both implementations behave the same contract-wise, of course).

Comment: Thank you. But I've read without using Spring, `MessagePrinter` **IS** dependent to some implementation of `MessageService`. Spring just makes it possible that it doesn't happen. So my question is still consistent.

Comment: By using an interface (`MessageService`), you already decouple from its implementations. A test is simple: does `MessageService` know anything about the implementations? The answer is 'no' (you don't even have them!). To achieve this, you just program with interfaces and use dependency injection. Spring is not a requirement (although it allows to use this pattern easily by constructing your application context for you).

Comment: I'm so confused. is `mockMessageService()` part of Spring or not?

Comment: Spring is a framework. In this case I believe you mean Spring IoC container which builds application context from your `@Configuration`-annotated class and injects dependencies. `mockMessageService()` is a method producing `MessageService` instance for this context; it is a part of your application and is not a part of Spring.